# Python TotalSegmentator in Flask App: RuntimeError with Multithreading - No root path found

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, multiprocessing

If I try to use the python api and try running TotalSegmentator in a new thread, I get the following error over and over again, until I kill the script:

Piece of code:

```
@app.route('/evaluation_page', methods=['POST'])
def evaluation():
    models_path = 'processing/prediction/train_models'
    results_path = 'processing/prediction/prediction_result'
    selected_file = 'upload/' + request.form['selectedFile']
    n_folds = request.form['numberOfFolds']
    n_repeats = request.form['numberOfRepeats']

    segmentation_thread = Thread(target=totalsegmentator, args=(selected_file, 'processing/segmentation/result'))
    segmentation_thread.start()

    evaluation_thread = Thread(target=evaluate, args=(selected_file, models_path, results_path, int(n_folds),
                                                      int(n_repeats)))
    evaluation_thread.start()
    return redirect(url_for('evaluation_page'))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
File "C:\Users\cserd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 120, in spawn_main
exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\cserd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 129, in _main
prepare(preparation_data)
File "C:\Users\cserd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 240, in prepare
_fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
File "C:\Users\cserd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 291, in _fixup_main_from_path
main_content = runpy.run_path(main_path,
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "", line 291, in run_path
File "", line 98, in _run_module_code
File "", line 88, in _run_code
File "C:\Users\cserd\PycharmProjects\ai-fistula-prediction\src\main.py", line 8, in
app = Flask(name)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\cserd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 566, in init
super().init(
File "C:\Users\cserd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\scaffold.py", line 112, in init
root_path = get_root_path(self.import_name)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\cserd\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\flask\helpers.py", line 631, in get_root_path
raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: No root path can be found for the provided module 'mp_main'. This can happen because the module came from an import hook that does not provide file name information or because it's a namespace package. In this case the root path needs to be explicitly provided.
```

This happens on MacOS, Linux and Windows. It is important to note, that I'm running TotalSegmentator from a Flask app. This is also the reason I need multithreading, so that the server stays responsive while the segmentation is happening.

Does anyone have an idea on how this issue can be fixed?

(I'm willing to use TotalSegmentator for a webapp, which makes outcome predictions in certain types of operations based on ct images and a large AI model)

I tried different approaches to run a new thread besides the basic "new Thread()", however none of those worked (I didn't even manage to start a new thread at all with any other approach).

I also tried running TotalSegmentator on it's own, that worked just fine.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by setting the FLASK_APP environment variable to my application's main Python file (typically main.py or app.py) and then using the flask run command to start the development server.

Seps:

Open the terminal or command prompt.
Navigate to the project's directory using the cd command.
Set the FLASK_APP environment variable to the name of the main Python file (e.g., main.py) using the following command:

```
export FLASK_APP=main.py
set FLASK_APP=main.py
```

Note: If you are using Windows, use set instead of export:
Start the Flask development server using the following command:
flask run

Happy coding!